# Slice list based on values in another list

Tags: python, list

I have long lists, for example:

```
list1 = ["a","a","b","b","c"]

list2 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]`
```

How can I slice the second list based on the first list (`list1` is sorted by its values)?

Like `[[1,3],[5,7],[9]]`

My lists are very long so I am looking for a fast way to precess this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and a bit of effort.

```
>>> [[b[1] for b in r] for p,r in itertools.groupby(zip(list1, list2), operator.itemgetter(0))]
[[1, 3], [5, 7], [9]]
```

Use `itertools.izip()` instead of `zip()` if you're running 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use a dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict

list1 = ["a","a","b","b","c"]
list2 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in zip(list1, list2):
    d[k].append(v)

>>> print([lst for lst in sorted(d.values())])
[[1, 3], [5, 7], [9]]
```